# Evidence for/against practical exams and their "added stress"

Tags: teaching, exams, assessment, emotional-responses

Numerous science course labs (especially anatomy labs) incorporate "**practical exams**" into their lab assessment. These exams involve having students visit multiple stations containing various visual components (e.g., models or specimens) for short time periods.

- Students have to identify or answer questions pertaining to the object at each station in only a few minutes (or less).

Are these types of exams actually *good*? Specifically, I'm wondering about the **added stress component** that is associated with these types of exams.

- These exams almost always bring about more student stress/anxiety due to a myriad of factors -- **is this stress unnecessary or necessary to the practical's utility?**

From my own schooling, I feel as though the stress associated with practical exams is positive as it trains you for real world scenarios in which you need to think on your feet. I have heard others, however, state just the opposite: that the stress of answering a question in <1min is not at all realistic and causes undue stress.

- I wonder if this is just one of those "well we had to go through it, so so should you" type of things without any actual support?
- The department I teach for has "heard the cries of the students", and has continuously tried to make the exams "less stressful." This includes:

  - Replacing a beeping watch "deemed too stressful" with a calm spoken phrase such as "change" or "move" during station shifts.
  - Providing clues at stations to focus students that are freaking out and struggling to focus
  - Providing numerous example test questions and "walk-throughs" prior to exams to prepare the students for what they will see.
  - Etc.

My Question: **is the added stress associated with practical exams both inherent to this exam type and, more importantly, is that added stress pedagogically supported? Alternatively, should we continue to make testing less stressful for students?**

- I want *hard* evidence: please answer only with cited materials discussing this topic.

  - Opinions and anecdotes are welcome, but please save them for the comments or chat only, thanks.

Comment: Are these exams specific to any country? I don't recall seeing anything of that kind, but I'm not into biology.

Comment: @svavil mpt that I'm aware of. It's pretty standard for anatomy, physiology, and various other types of hands-on biology labs.